# CakePHP cookies not persisting after browser close

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, nginx, cakephp-2.0

I am in the process of moving away from Apache in favor of nginx due to the lower resource consumption. I have set up an Ubuntu Server box with the LEMP stack installed. After moving all my applications over (3 CakePHP 2.0.5 apps, 1 Wordpress install), everything seems to be working perfectly except for one thing - Cake's cookies suddenly disappear when the browser is closed.

I have created a very simple test PHP page to test if cookies are working at all and they are in fact working, just not in Cake. Wordpress is also not having any troubles remembering me when I close my browser.

Using the Chrome developer tools, I have inspected to see if the cookie is being set at all, and it is as you can see below:

[image: Cookies being set]

The expiry date is even set a month into the future as well, so I don't understand why they don't live past browser close. As soon as I fire my browser up and navigate to my app, the cookie is now gone:

[image: Cookie is gone!]

One thing I did notice is that with my app running on Apache, the `CAKEPHP` cookie you see above above has the same value before and after close. However on the nginx server, that cookie has a different value everytime I close and re-open my browser.

I thought this might have to do with sessions, so I checked my session settings in `core.php` and it's set to let PHP do the session handling:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'
));
```

I've checked my `/tmp` directory and session files are being created. I tried changing the session handler to `cake` so that Cake would store sessions in its `app/tmp/sessions` directory, and while the sessions would successfully get created in this directory my cookies are still lost on browser close.

Has anybody experienced this behavior between nginx and Cake before, or have any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to encrypted cookies and the Suhosin patch. Apparently Suhosin ignores any `mt_srand()` and `srand()` calls you make and initializes the randomizer itself [[see here](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/13/php-srand-problems-with-suhosin/)]. Because Cake relies on these functions, it was interfering with my encrypted cookies. To fix it, I added these two lines to my php.ini file and rebooted the server (note that simply restarting nginx didn't work):

```
suhosin.srand.ignore = Off
suhosin.mt_srand.ignore = Off
```