# Remember me with cakephp Auth Login

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to implement remember me functionality in cakephp.First time when user hits the domain login page should appear, if user clicks the remember me check box while login, when next time user hits the domain it should redirect to another page not the login page, if remember me is not checked then login page should appear.

Here remember me is working, but if user is logged in in need to display the **userhome** page not the **login** page

how can i implement this.

Thanks for the help...

Here is my code i am working on:

routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action'=>'login'));
Router::connect('/:action', 
array('controller' => 'users', 'action' =>    'userhome'),
array('pass' => array('')));
```

AppController.php

```
public $components = array(
'Session','Auth' => array('loginRedirect' => 
array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'userhome'),
'logoutRedirect' => '/','authorize'=>array('Controller'),),'Cookie');


public function beforeFilter() {
$this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;
if (!$this->Auth->loggedIn() && $this->Cookie->read('rememberMe')) {
        $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('rememberMe');
        echo debug($cookie);
        $this->loadModel('User'); // If the User model is not loaded already
        $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                        'User.username' => $cookie['username'],
                        'User.password' => $cookie['password']
                )
        ));

public function login() {
if($this->request->is('post')){

if ($this->Auth->login())  {

    if ($this->request->data['User']['rememberMe'] == 1) {
                        // After what time frame should the cookie expire
    $cookieTime = "12 months"; // You can do e.g: 1 week, 17 weeks, 14 days

    // remove "remember me checkbox"
    unset($this->request->data['User']['rememberMe']);

    // hash the user's password
    $this->request->data['User']['password'] =    $this->Auth->password($this->request->data['User']['password']);

// write the cookie
    $this->Cookie->write('rememberMe', $this->request->data['User'], true, $cookieTime);
}



$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());


}


}




}

        if ($user && !$this->Auth->login($user['User'])) {
            $this->redirect('/users/logout'); // destroy session &   cookie
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('rememberMe', array('type' => 'checkbox',
'label' => 'Remember me','class'=>'rememberme')); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand your nested `function login()`, but I assume it is just sample from your `/users/login` action, so let me rewrite the `beforeFilter` method to redirect your user to `/users/userhome` if he hits your domain and is logged in using cookie:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Cookie->httpOnly = true;
    if (!$this->Auth->loggedIn() && $this->Cookie->read('rememberMe')) {
            $cookie = $this->Cookie->read('rememberMe');
            debug($cookie); // no need to echo it, debug function does that already
            $this->loadModel('User'); // If the User model is not loaded already
            $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                            'User.username' => $cookie['username'],
                            'User.password' => $cookie['password']
                    )
            ));

        if ($user && !$this->Auth->login($user['User'])) {
            $this->redirect('/users/logout'); // destroy session &   cookie
        } else {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); // redirect to Auth.redirect if it is set, else to Auth.loginRedirect ('/users/userhome') if it is set, else to /
        }
    }
}
```

FYI: `$this->Auth->redirect()` is deprecated as of 2.3, use `$this->Auth->redirectUrl()` instead

Comment: Here i am facing another problem.when i close my browser cookie is getting destroyed, event if i check remember me check box while login. In my php.ini file cookielifetime is set to 0.

Comment: Are you sure you don't destroy the cookie in your AppController in afterFilter method or some leftover test code? Otherwise try to search similar questions. Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301425/cakephp-cookies-not-persisting-after-browser-close) maybe?

Comment: thanks i have solved it, the remember me cookie was not set properly, now it's working